# Check index for 2D list and print out the index based on 2D list

Tags: python, list

I wanted to try another example such to print the index for 2D list. Example:

```
a = [["text", "man","chest","funny"],["cruel", "just","for","testing"],["I", "take","this","for"],["learning", "purpose","only","please"] ]

b = [["text", "funny"], ["cruel"],["I", "take"], ["for","learning", "purpose"]]

ba = ["text", "funny", "purpose"]
```

My code is something like this:

```
store_x = []

for x in b:
    for i,xx in enumerate(x):
        if xx in ba:
            store_x.append(i)


print(store_x)

dic2 = []    
for x,y in zip(store_x,a):
    result = []
    for u in str(x):
        dic2.append(y[int(u)])

print(dic2)
```

Current output:

```
[0, 1, 2]
['text', 'just', 'this']
```

Expected output:

```
[0][0,1],[3][2] # {b} based on {ba} Not sure whether this is how the index #should be look like for 2D
[["text","man"],["only"]] # store_x based on {a}
```

I wanted to first find the index value of {b} based on {ba} and then from the index value, I will use it to print the value from {a} by using the index stored in {store_x}

New:

Here is another questions when we play around with the {ba} elements. Example,

```
a = [["text", "funny"], ["cruel"],["I", "take"], ["for","learning", "purpose"]]
b = [["text", "funny"], ["cruel"],["I", "take"], ["for","learning", "purpose"]]

ba = ["funny","text", "take","new","I", "purpose", "learning", "cruel"]
```

Then the code I am currently using is:

store_x = {}

```
for ex, x in enumerate(b):
    row = []
    for i, xx in enumerate(x):
        if xx in ba:
            row.append(i)
    if row:
        store_x[ex] = row

print(store_x)

order = {e: ii for ii, e in enumerate(ba)}

dic2 = []
for i, x in store_x.items():
    row = []
    if x:
        for ex in x:
            dic2.append(a[i][ex])

    if dic2:
        dic2.sort(key=lambda e: order.get(e, len(ba)))


print(dic2)
```

The store_x values appeared to be:

```
{0: [0, 1], 1: [0], 2: [0, 1], 3: [1, 2]}
```

and not what I expected it to be:

```
{0: [1, 0], 2: [1,0], 3: [2, 1], 1: [0]}
```

The current dic2: (which is correct but the store_x value is not what I expected it to be)

```
['funny', 'text', 'take', 'I', 'purpose', 'learning', 'cruel']
```

Updates!

I try to use my new code:

```
s = []

for ex, x in enumerate(ba):
    store_x = {}
    for i, xx in enumerate(b):
        if x in xx:

            store_x[i] = [xx.index(x)]
    s.append(store_x)


print(s)
dic2 = []
for x in s:
    for i, xx in x.items():
        row = []
        if xx:
            for u in xx:
                dic2.append(a[i][u])

print(dic2)
```

The output is:

```
[{0: [1]}, {0: [0]}, {2: [1]}, {}, {2: [0]}, {3: [2]}, {3: [1]}, {1: [0]}]
['funny', 'text', 'take', 'I', 'purpose', 'learning', 'cruel']
```

But still this isn't the output I expecting:

My expected output:

```
{0: [1, 0], 2: [1,0], 3: [2, 1], 1: [0]}
```

Can anyone help me with this pls.

Above All SOLVED!

Found another problem.

Code:

```
a = [["text", "funny"], ["cruel"],["I", "take"], ["for","learning", "purpose"], ["learning", "to", "learning", "when", "I", "have", "time", "for", "learning"]]
b = [["text", "funny"], ["cruel"],["I", "take"], ["for","learning", "purpose"], ["learning", "to", "learning", "when", "I", "have", "time", "for", "learning"]]

ba = ["funny","text","learning", "take","new","I", "purpose", "cruel"]
```

When applied solution from Daniel Mesejo(Good guy).

The output becomes:

```
{0: [1, 0], 1: [0], 2: [1, 0], 3: [1, 2], 4: [0, 2, 7]}
['funny', 'text', 'learning', 'learning', 'learning', 'learning', 'take', 'I', 'purpose', 'cruel']
```

Expected output should be: (given that "learning" has appear one time so we should not include it again)

```
{0: [1, 0], 1: [0], 2: [1,0], 3: [1,2], 4: [0, 2, 8,4]} <---- (my idea is that since "learning" appears 3 times here, maybe we should take one time only despite which index it is in). With this, it could be 4:[0] or [2] or [8].
```

The "I" appears in two different index for 2D list. My idea is take either one of the index and return only 1 time.  It could be 2:[1,0] or 4: [0,4] or 4: [2,4] or 4: [8,4]

```
['funny', 'text', 'learning', 'take', 'I', 'purpose', 'cruel']
```

Hopefully this can be done too. I am still trying my best to learn more. Thank you for the help all this time.

Solved! Here for future reference:

```
store_x = {}
vex = []
for ex, x in enumerate(b):
    row = []
    for i, xx in enumerate(x):
        if xx not in vex:
            if xx in ba:          
                row.append(i)
                vex.append(xx)
    if row:
        row.sort(key=lambda e: ba.index(x[e]))
        store_x[ex] = row

print(store_x)

order = {e: ii for ii, e in enumerate(ba)}

dic2 = []
for i, x in store_x.items():
    if x:
        for ex in x:
            dic2.append(a[i][ex])
dic2.sort(key=lambda e: order.get(e, len(ba)))
print(dic2)
```

Comment: What do the values in your expected output mean? Your explanation is, at least to me, unclear.

Comment: Hi, I have updated it and please check. My new output should be something like the updated version

Comment: Can anyone help me with this pls?

Comment: What is the input in your last example?

Comment: Its solved thank you sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
store_x = []
for x in b:
    row = []
    for i, xx in enumerate(x):
        if xx in ba:
            row.append(i)
    store_x.append(row)

print(store_x)

dic2 = []
for i, x in enumerate(store_x):
    row = []
    if x:
        for ex in x:
            row.append(a[i][ex])
    dic2.append(row)

print(dic2)
```

**Output**

```
[[0, 1], [], [], [2]]
[['text', 'man'], [], [], ['only']]
```

The output can be read as `store_x` has in index 0 the value `[0,1]` and in index 3 `[2]`.

The problem in your code is that `store_x` is a list and you need a list of lists (2D list). One alternative is to use a dictionary in the first loop:

```
store_x = {}
for ex, x in enumerate(b):
    row = []
    for i, xx in enumerate(x):
        if xx in ba:
            row.append(i)
    if row:
        store_x[ex] = row

print(store_x)

dic2 = []
for i, x in store_x.items():
    row = []
    if x:
        for ex in x:
            row.append(a[i][ex])
    if row:
        dic2.append(row)

print(dic2)
```

**Output**

```
{0: [0, 1], 3: [2]}
[['text', 'man'], ['only']]
```

That is more like the expected output.

**UPDATE**
As specified in the comments the output most follow the order of ba, assuming a value missing from ba must come last. The code must be updated to:

```
store_x = {}
for ex, x in enumerate(b):
    row = []
    for i, xx in enumerate(x):
        if xx in ba:
            row.append(i)
    if row:
        store_x[ex] = row

print(store_x)

order = {e: ii for ii, e in enumerate(ba)}

dic2 = []
for i, x in store_x.items():
    row = []
    if x:
        for ex in x:
            row.append(a[i][ex])

    if row:
        row.sort(key=lambda e: order.get(e, len(ba)))
        dic2.append(row)

print(dic2)
```

**Output (Test Case 1)**

```
{0: [0, 1], 3: [2]}
[['text', 'man'], ['only']]
```

**Output (Test Case 2)**

```
{0: [0], 2: [1], 3: [1, 2]}
[['text'], ['take'], ['purpose', 'learning']]
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
store_x = {}
for ex, x in enumerate(b):
    row = []
    for i, xx in enumerate(x):
        if xx in ba:
            row.append(i)
    if row:
        row.sort(key=lambda e: ba.index(x[e]))
        store_x[ex] = row

print(store_x)

order = {e: ii for ii, e in enumerate(ba)}

dic2 = []
for i, x in store_x.items():
    if x:
        for ex in x:
            dic2.append(a[i][ex])
dic2.sort(key=lambda e: order.get(e, len(ba)))
print(dic2)
```

**Output (Test Case 1)**

```
{0: [0, 1], 3: [2]}
['text', 'man', 'only']
```

**Output (Test Case 2)**

```
{0: [0], 2: [1], 3: [2, 1]}
['text', 'take', 'purpose', 'learning']
```

**Output (Test Case 3)**

```
{0: [1, 0], 1: [0], 2: [1, 0], 3: [2, 1]}
['funny', 'text', 'take', 'I', 'purpose', 'learning', 'cruel']
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir. This is exactly what I wanted it to be and I will revise it more.

Comment: Sir, there is a problem. For example, when I try this a = [["text", "funny"], ["cruel"],["I", "take"], ["for","learning", "purpose"]]..... b = [["text", "funny"], ["cruel"],["I", "take"], ["for","learning", "purpose"]].... ba = ["text", "take", "purpose", "learning"] and I used the code you shown, the output seems to be different from expected. Current output : ['text', 'take', 'learning', 'purpose']..... expected output : ['text', 'take', 'purpose', 'learning']

Comment: Does the output must be sorted by the order of the ba list?

Comment: It should follow the order of ba list but index based on the b then search from a

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Sorry for asking again but I am just curious whether will it be possible to make the store_x = {0: [0, 1], 2: [0, 1], 3: [2,1]} instead of {0: [0, 1], 2: [0, 1], 3: [1, 2]}? I would like to learn about the list whether the index can be stored into the list without appending it in order. It will be great if we can just take the index and then store accordingly.

Comment: For example, I found another leak there is when we play around with {ba}. I have updated in the questions.

Comment: I tried using your code and applied the updated {ba} from my re-edit question ba = ["funny","text", "take","new","I", "purpose", "learning", "cruel"] and get [['funny', 'text'], ['cruel'], ['take', 'I'], ['purpose', 'learning']] which is not the expected output

Comment: Sir can you help me with this problem? Please

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Sir, can I know how it works for the key=lambda e:ba.index(x[e])? I am still learning and what will this lambda get for input and the output?

Comment: If possible, I would like to understand more about the key=lambda e: order.get(e, len(dic)). Could you explain, please.

Comment: order is a dictionary that have the strings as the keys and indices as values. The get function returns the index of e, if e is in the dictionary otherwise returns the last index

Comment: Thank you and what about the key=lambda e:ba.index(x[e])?

Comment: x[e] returns the value of x in e and ba.index() returns the index of x[e] in ba, key is parameter that sort receives and is the value that is used to sort the list

Comment: So is it mean that x[e] and the e is the value from row that are [0, 1]
[0]
[0, 1]
[1, 2, 3]? So for x[e] it will be ["text", "funny"][0]?

Comment: It means if x is a list x = ['a', b, 'c'] and e = 0, x[e] = 'a' if e = 2 x[e] = 'c'

Comment: Hi sir, I am sorry for troubling you again but I found another problem here when using the code. I am still learning and trying to play around with list. For example, when my a = [["text", "funny"], ["cruel"],["I", "take"], ["for","learning", "purpose"], ["learning", "to", "learning", "when", "i", "have", "time", "for", "learning"]]
b = [["text", "funny"], ["cruel"],["I", "take"], ["for","learning", "purpose"], ["learning", "to", "learning", "when", "i", "have", "time", "for", "learning"]]

ba = ["funny","text","learning" "take","new","I", "purpose", "learning", "cruel"]. Then output wrong

Comment: I have updated a new one above regarding my findings.